# File permissions changing after editing with Notepad++ on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, notepad++, windows-11, file-permissions, xml

I'm using a program which creates settings files in XML format.
Out of curiosity, I opened said XML file, changed the property that contains the name of the profile (not the file name!) and saved it. I was using Notepad for this.

When I opened the program again, it correctly displayed the value I just changed. This means the program can access and read the file.
But when I tried changing the profile name or deleting it, the program tells me that it can't complete the action and I should check file permissions.

**Troubleshooting I already tried:**

- Checked the permissions and they are exactly the same as before
- Looked at the file encoding and it also was exactly the same
- Tried comparing the files with Meld to see if any invisible symbols or line
  endings were added, but the files are exactly the same, except for
  the string I changed

Any Ideas what else I should try? The Program in question is Fuji X Raw Studio.

Comment: Notepad OR Notepad++?

Comment: Notepad++, but since then I did in fact try the normal Notepad and VS Code again on a fresh file to see if it makes any difference. It does not.

Answer (score 0):

DUH
I found it out after some additional troubleshooting:
While the encoding I needed was UTF-8 with BOM, it got changed to just UTF-8 when saving it with Notepad++. Now it works!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).